# Does Youtube autocaption Hebrew? If not, why not?

Tags: youtube, subtitles, caption

I've uploaded videos in Hebrew onto Youtube, and can't get it to autocaption them. Neither can I find any autocaptioned videos in Hebrew on Youtube either. That's weird; Youtube autocaptions all sorts of languages, and it's not like Israel is a stranger to technology…

Comment: Questions about YouTube are out of scope here at Super User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per:

> Automatic captions are available in English, Dutch, French, German,
>   Italian, Japanese, Korean, Portuguese, Russian, and Spanish.
>
> YouTube is constantly improving its speech recognition technology. However, automatic captions might misrepresent the spoken content due to mispronunciations, accents, dialects, or background noise. You should always review automatic captions and edit any parts that haven't been properly transcribed.
>
> **https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6373554?hl=en**